# Text in grid when loading data

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

The "Loading..." text in grids should be translated to the device language right ? I ask because the text do not get the device language someone know why ? In advanced I already load the languages in the KB.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet or better yet the full code part?

Comment: hi indofraiser i do not have code because i talk about the default text of grid when grid charging data and its spend some time one the grid show the text "Loading..." this text I talk about if should be use the device language por example in spanish "Cargando..." and not Loading... understand ?

Comment: Try this page: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations -- <html lang="es" xml:lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">--

Comment: Did you set property Translation type to "Runtime Translation" ? Ref. : http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?9126

Comment: Hi Armin, I set Translation type to "Runtime" as your instruction but grid keep show Loading instead of Cargando (ES) or Carregando (PT) in advanced all languages is marked and I do rebiuld all after change of Translation Type property, any other way ?  thx.

Comment: Armin forgot my above comment I was set the Translation Type in wrong environment, now it works fine, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try including that string in an event or a procedure. You don't need to use it anywhere.
Like this:

```
&String = "Loading..."
```

Save and build the object, and that string should appear on your language object for translation.

Sometimes I need to do this when I have text on a grid, table or other element on screen. For some reason, Genexus doesn't find those strings for translation, but I couldn't find the exact reason why, it seems random.